# Problems in the levels of breadth first display

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, breadth-first-search

I want to insert my import by using a tree format, which records the data and the levels.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Node {
    public int iData; // data item (key)
    public double dData; // data item
    public Node leftChild; // this node's left child
    public Node rightChild; // this node's right child
    public int level;

    public void displayNode() // display ourself
    {
        System.out.print('{');
        System.out.print(level);
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print(iData);
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print(dData);
        System.out.print("} ");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
} // end class Node
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Tree {
private Node root; // first node of tree

// -------------------------------------------------------------
public Tree() // constructor
{
    root = null;
} // no nodes in tree yet
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void insert(int id, double dd) {
    Node newNode = new Node(); // make new node
    newNode.iData = id; // insert data
    newNode.dData = dd;
    if (root == null) // no node in root
        root = newNode;
    else // root occupied
    {
        Node current = root; // start at root
        Node parent;
        while (true) // (exits internally)
        {
            parent = current;
            if (id < current.iData) // go left?
            {
                current = current.leftChild;
                if (current == null) // if end of the line,
                { // insert on left
                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            } // end if go left
            else // or go right?
            {
                current = current.rightChild;
                if (current == null) // if end of the line
                { // insert on right
                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            } // end else go right
        } // end while
    } // end else not root
} // end insert()
// -------------------------------------------------------------

public void breadthFirstDisplay() {
    Queue newQueue = new LinkedList();
    newQueue.add(root);
    while (!newQueue.isEmpty()){
        Node theNode = (Node) newQueue.remove();
        theNode.displayNode();
        if (theNode.leftChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.leftChild);
            theNode.level ++;
        }
        if (theNode.rightChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.rightChild);
            theNode.level ++;
        }
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
} // end class Tree
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class TreeApp {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Tree theTree = new Tree();

    theTree.insert(50, 1.5);
    theTree.insert(25, 1.2);
    theTree.insert(75, 1.7);
    theTree.insert(12, 1.5);
    theTree.insert(37, 1.2);
    theTree.insert(43, 1.7);
    theTree.insert(30, 1.5);
    theTree.insert(33, 1.2);
    theTree.insert(87, 1.7);
    theTree.insert(93, 1.5);
    theTree.insert(97, 1.5);

    theTree.breadthFirstDisplay();

}// -------------------------------------------------------------
} // end class TreeApp
// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

**Output:**

```
0, 50, 1.5  
0, 25, 1.2  
0, 75, 1.7  
0, 12, 1.5  
0, 37, 1.2  
0, 87, 1.7  
0, 30, 1.5  
0, 43, 1.7  
0, 93, 1.5  
0, 33, 1.2  
0, 97, 1.5
```

Why the level will display all in 0 ?

Sorry that maybe my question of levels is not clear.
The levels should be how many times of shifting required in a tree.
My expected result is:

**Output:**

```
0, 50, 1.5  
1, 25, 1.2  
1, 75, 1.7  
2, 12, 1.5  
2, 37, 1.2  
2, 87, 1.7  
3, 30, 1.5  
3, 43, 1.7  
3, 93, 1.5  
4, 33, 1.2  
4, 97, 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `theNode.displayNode();` from start while loop to end(after conditions) and should be display level, but I'm not sure, if your implementation is correct - I will have to look on it more.

Edit: I'm not sure, if this, what you wanted to achieve by `level` is number of direct childs of node - if yes, then it is displaying it. But if `level` should be info, how far you are from root, then it it will be better to move calculating level to main loop of adding elements, and there increasing it.

Comment: My original expectation is counting how many times of shifting required in a tree, but not the number of times using if.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are displaying node BEFORE you are changing the level:

```
// instead of this in your code
Node theNode = (Node) newQueue.remove();
theNode.displayNode();
if (theNode.leftChild != null) {
    newQueue.add(theNode.leftChild);
    theNode.level ++;
}
if (theNode.rightChild != null) {
    newQueue.add(theNode.rightChild);
    theNode.level ++;
}

// do this
Node theNode = (Node) newQueue.remove();
if (theNode.leftChild != null) {
    newQueue.add(theNode.leftChild);
    theNode.level ++;
}
if (theNode.rightChild != null) {
    newQueue.add(theNode.rightChild);
    theNode.level ++;
}
theNode.displayNode(); // move display here
```

Comment: My original expectation is counting how many times of shifting required in a tree, but not the number of times using if.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following method:

```
public void breadthFirstDisplay() {
    Queue newQueue = new LinkedList();
    newQueue.add(root);
    while (!newQueue.isEmpty()){
        Node theNode = (Node) newQueue.remove();
        theNode.displayNode();
        if (theNode.leftChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.leftChild);
            theNode.level ++;
        }
        if (theNode.rightChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.rightChild);
            theNode.level ++;
        }
    }
}
```

You are calling `theNode.displayNode();` **before** incrementing the level with `theNode.level ++;`.

Try moving `theNode.displayNode();` to the end of the `while` loop, as follows:

```
public void breadthFirstDisplay() {
    Queue newQueue = new LinkedList();
    newQueue.add(root);
    while (!newQueue.isEmpty()){
        Node theNode = (Node) newQueue.remove();
        // theNode.displayNode();
        if (theNode.leftChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.leftChild);
            theNode.level ++;
        }
        if (theNode.rightChild != null) {
            newQueue.add(theNode.rightChild);
            theNode.level ++;
        }
        theNode.displayNode(); // moved here
    }
}
```

Comment: My original expectation is counting how many times of shifting required in a tree, but not the number of times using if.

Answer (score 0):

My original expectation is counting how many times of shifting required in a tree, but not the number of times using if.

Comment: Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27211127/edit) your original post to add additional information.